# Keep collapsed navbar from reordering pull-right elements?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following code ([full source of page](http://pastebin.com/sgVSnL7u)):

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">

  <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>

  <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
  <span class="brand" href="#">Test</span>


  <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav">
     <li class="{% active request "^/$" %}"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class="{% active request "^/about$" %}"><a href="#">About</a></li>
   </ul>


    <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
      <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search...">
    </form>
    <div class="navbar-form pull-right">
     <a href="{% url "login" %}" class="btn">Log in</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
  </div>
</div>
```

When loaded as a desktop, I get this:
[image: Loaded as desktop]
Note that the "Log in" and "Sign up" buttons are BEFORE the search bar.

However, when I resize the browser, and the navbar responds I get this:
[image: mobile version]

Now, the "Log in" and "Sign up" buttons are AFTER the search bar. This is because they are pull-right elements.

I've tried wrapping the buttons and search bar in a `float: right` parent div. This causes them to stay in the right order, but results in them being weirdly off to the side. This is undesirable. Does anyone have a solution that causes their order not to be reversed?

Comment: Could you post your css code as well, we can't answer without it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sgVSnL7u
I'm using the default bootstrap CSS, and the all of my own is in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the floats on `navbar-form` and `navbar-search` are set to none once the `nav-collapse` logic kicks in. Instead of relying on floats, play around with `display: inline-block`. The following seems to work reasonably (you should create your own classes instead of applying styles inline):

```
    <div class="pull-right">
    <!-- .btn's already have display: inline-block so don't need to apply it manually -->
    <!-- margin-left: 15px is applied so that the buttons align with the 
        search field -->
        <a style="margin-left: 15px;" href="#" class="btn">Log in</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</a>
        <form class="navbar-form" style="display:inline-block">
            <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search...">
        </form>     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Navbar's no longer use .pull-left or .pull-right, but rather .navbar-left and .navbar-right. This avoids issues with specificity due to chaining classes and enables easier styling.

See http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/13/bootstrap-3-rc2/